# What's wrong with my implementation of this angle calculation formula?

Tags: algorithm, autohotkey, trigonometry

So I need to figure out the angle between two points, which should be trivial. I found at least 5 different questions about this on SO. But as I tried multiple algorithms, I'm getting wrong results, so I'll lay out my setup:

First, this part *shouldn't* be problematic, but I'll lay it out anyway because it is part of the process and could be the source of the error, but basically I'm generating a list of degrees between 0 and 360 as keys to pixel coordinates in a circle around the center of the screen:

```
getRadialPixels(){
    centerX := 960
    centerY := 540
    distance := 250
    pixels := []
    loop, 360
    {
        Fi := A_Index * 3.14159265359 / 180
        x := Round(centerX + distance * Cos(Fi))
        y := Round(centerY + distance * Sin(Fi))
        realDegree := A_Index + 90
        if (realDegree > 360)
        {
            realDegree := realDegree - 360
        }
        pixels[realDegree] := {}
        pixels[realDegree]["x"] := x
        pixels[realDegree]["y"] := y
        ;FileAppend, % "Added coordinate [" . x . ", " . y . "] to radial list for degree " . realDegree . ".`n", Log.txt
    }
    return pixels
}
```

You'll see that I'm adding 90 degrees to each key, then normalizing it to a 360 degree limit because basically I want 0 degrees to be at the top [0,1], 90 degrees to be to the right [1,0] and so on, which adding 90 degrees seemed to achieve. I got the formula from elsewhere, but I tested this and I *think* it's right. I don't think that code is the problem, but it's there just in case.

The actual formula for calculating the angle between two points is here:

```
getAngleBetweenPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    angle := floor(atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / 3.14159265359)
    if (angle > 359) {
        angle := angle - 360
    }
    if (angle < 0) {
        angle := 360 - abs(angle)
    }
    return angle
}
```

And I also tried:

```
angle := ceil((ACos((x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / (Sqrt(x1**2 + y1**2) * Sqrt(x2**2 + y2**2))) * 57.2957795) * 180 / 3.14159265359)
```

And as a side-note, I had to add atan2 to AHK, since it isn't supported natively:

```
atan2(x,y) {    ; 4-quadrant atan
   Return dllcall("msvcrt\atan2","Double",y, "Double",x, "CDECL Double")
}
```

But both versions seem to be getting incorrect results. By far. What am I doing wrong?

Tests:

```
originX := 0
originY := 0

x1 := 0
y1 := 1

x2 := 1
y2 := 0

x3 := 0
y3 := -1

x4 := -1
y4 := 0

x5 := 1
y5 := 1

x6 := 1
y6 := -1

x7 := -1
y7 := -1

x8 := -1
y8 := 1

result1 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x1,y1) ; 0 deg
result2 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x2,y2) ; 89 deg
result3 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x3,y3) ; 179 deg
result4 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x4,y4) ; 270 deg
result5 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x5,y5) ; 44 deg
result6 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x6,y6) ; 134 deg
result7 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x7,y7) ; 225 deg
result8 := getAngleBetweenPoints(originX,originY,x8,y8) ; 315 deg
```

Comment: Test results I just posted are wrongly calculated based on the code shown, will update right away with ones calculated properly based on displayed code.

Comment: Updated / fixed to proper tests.

Comment: Could you attach a simple picture with the two points and angle required?

Comment: @Sergey http://i.imgur.com/TB0GJNt.png

Comment: It is two points and line segment, but where is the angle?

Comment: @Sergey the line segment represent the desired angle to be known. The angle between the two points, between 0 and 360 degrees (with 0 & 360 degrees being at [0,1] on a 4 quadrant grid). Does that make it clear?

Comment: @Viziionary: You have x and y swapped in the definition of `atan2` :)

Comment: @tom Could that have been my whole problem? T_T lol - I'll test.

Comment: @Viziionary That angle? http://imgur.com/a/sBpvC

Comment: @Sergey Yeah! Sorry for not being more clear about that, I didnt realize.

Comment: What is OY axis direction for your case - up or down?

Comment: @MBo What do you mean OY? Look at Sergey's illustration - it's exactly accurate.

Comment: Oh, nevermind... Are what results for origin point (0,0) and set (0,1), (1,0), (0,-1), (-1.0) do you want to get?

Comment: @MBo It's fixed now! The solution was tom's comment

Comment: @tom your comment was the answer.

Comment: So what was the purpose of 90 degrees shift?

Comment: @MBo I'm a little confused why it's needed myself, but it works. Basically before the 90 degrees shift on the degree "list" (and the algorithm, which I didnt mention, but was needed after the fix too) 0 degrees didnt start at the top [0,1], which I wanted it to - after the 90 degree shift, 0 degrees starts at the top as desired.

Comment: But 90 degrees shift causes exchange of `atan2` arguments (`cos(90-fi)=sin(fi)` and so on). OK, in any case you have got what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have x and y swapped in the definition of `atan2`, it should be y first and then x:

```
atan2(y,x) {    ; 4-quadrant atan
   Return dllcall("msvcrt\atan2","Double",y, "Double",x, "CDECL Double")
}
```